# How can I provide options inside slots with Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I want to get multiple information from a certain node using slots.
One thing is, I want to give options for some of the questions I prompt.
Example: the user will make a reservation. I'm capturing date and time with the slot, and also where does he want the table. For the table part, I would like to provide him with two options "inside" or "outside".

Is that possible using slots?

Comment: Have you looked at what to prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is coming soon. At this point, you need to export the entire workspace json and manually edit it there, we don't have GUI support just yet.